# Using function return for another template function C++

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I am trying to call a templated function using the return of another function, but I cannot seem to get it working.

```
enum class MYENUM {
    X1,X2
};

MYENUM SomeFunc() {
    return MYENUM::X1;
}

template<MYENUM T>
void ENUMFunc() {
    //do something
}

int main() {
    ENUMFunc<MYENUM::X1>(); //works
    ENUMFunc<SomeFunc()>(); //error?
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can only use a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) for the value of a [non-type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter).  To get that, you need to mark `SomeFunc` as `constexpr` like

```
constexpr MYENUM SomeFunc() {
    return MYENUM::X1;
}
```

which will now let you use it for the template parameter as seen in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d97f9f3a52c6cfb3)